# Finding convergence parameter

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, parameter-estimation

Find the value of the parameter $p$ for which the following series converge. Series of:

$\frac{1}{(ln(k))^p}$

from $2$ to $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

There are no values of $p$ for which this series converges. Are you sure you stated the problem correctly?

Comment: Yes, and thank you for answering